# What will happen if two beacons with different regions transmit simultaneously

Tags: android, ios, core-location, ibeacon, altbeacon

Let suppose I am monitoring two regions:

`region 1 (ABCDEFAB-E95D-433C-BCF4-643BECC5DFFF (UUID),4(MAJOR),4(MINOR))`

and

`region 2 (ABCDEFAB-E95D-433C-BCF4-643BECC5DFFF (UUID),4(MAJOR),5(MINOR))`

If both tags are placed closed to each other, what will happen?

- Enter region 1
- Enter region 2

or

- Enter region 1
- Exit  region 1
- Enter region 2
- Exit  region 2

Comment: for -1 please specify reason

Comment: what i am trying to say there is a possibility cell phone will receive both beacons with different regions, so what will happen than ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former will happen.  You will not receive an exit until you exit the region.  You can think about it from the standpoint of how many beacons can you detect at once - you don't need to stop being in one region just because you detect you are in another.  (All things being equal and ignoring iOS region monitoring restrictions.)

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/caseycoding/0602617b222263d807d2) in objective-c where you can try this out using iBeacons and core-location.  (Of course plug in your respective iBeacon info at the top.)

Comment: thats what i need to know, but it costs me -2 dont know why.